# Remove a specific polyline in google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

I'm drawing polylines in google map v2 using marker drag, this is my code

```
int startDraw = 1;
Polyline polyline;
List<LatLng> lineCordinates = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    // startDraw == 0 --> stop draw
    // startDraw == 1 --> start draw

if (startDraw == 1) {

    Integer markerId = markerMapHash.get(marker);

    if (markerId == null) {
        markerId = 1;
    }

    if (markerId == 1) {
        lineCordinates.add(marker.getPosition());

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < lineCordinates.size(); i++) {

        polyline = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(lineCordinates)
        .width(lineWidth)
        .color(lineColor));

        polylines.add(polyline);

    }
    }

   }


@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    lineCordinates.clear(); 
    if (startDraw == 1) {
        startDraw = 0;
    }else{
        startDraw = 1;
    }

   }
```

and to remove all polylines, this is the code in a button onClick

```
 for(Polyline line : polylines){
  line.remove();
}
polylines.clear();
```

Now I want to remove a specific polyline, how can I do this ?
Hope anyone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "specific polyline".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never messed with this code before, but I assume you just need to check to see if `line` matches the specific polyline you're looking for and then remove it. Something like this:

```
for(Polyline line : polylines)
{
    if (isSpecificPolyline(line))
        line.remove();
}
```

Comment: Comparing objects using `==` will almost never do any good. In case of Google Maps Android API v2 this is more than true, because these objects are proxies and it often happens that two separate objects are the same real object in a different process.